# Azure Devops keeps asking for approval which has been given

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, we are trying to start a deploy to an environment. According to the policy, one approver must approve this.

After a person has given approval, the deploy is not started and Azure Devops keeps saying that at least 1 approver must approve. See the screenshot below, which shows that contradictory information is given. (A second approver also opened the page, by the way, but did not have the option to give approval... Probably because it was already given and so all approval requirements are met.)

[image]

We also tried changing the configuration, such that not one person in the list but rather a person in a group had to give approval. The same problem occurred, as seen in the screenshow below.

[image]

Does anyone know what could be wrong here? The information from Azure DevOps is contradictory with itself.

(Interesting detail is that this has worked until recently. We have no idea why it's suddenly broken.)

Comment: In the meantime, it seems that deploys are started again after approval... I don't think we changed any configuration, so it seems like there was a glitch in the automated start of jobs. Still not sure why that happened, and bad communication in the UI from Azure DevOps (keep asking for approval when there's approval). Doesn't say anything about the actual issue. But anyway, it's working again.

Answer (score 0):

Please Click the "TST" resource to check the advanced setting, check if enable the "Allow approvers to approve their own runs".

[image: approvals]

And try to remove it and create a new "Approvals and checks" and to check if it works.

For more information, you could refer to [approvals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#approvals).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think we haven't changed this setting recently, so it's probably not involved in our problem.